# How to create a Pandas dataframe from another column in a dataframe by splitting it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, exploratory-data-analysis

I have the following source dataframe

| Person | Country | Is Rich? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | US | Yes |
| 1 | India | No |
| 2 | India | Yes |
| 3 | US | Yes |
| 4 | US | Yes |
| 5 | India | No |
| 6 | US | No |
| 7 | India | No |

I need to convert it another dataframe for plotting a bar graph like below for easily accessing data

[Bar chart of economic status per country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2gIm.png)

Data frame to be created is like below.

| Country | Rich | Poor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | 3 | 1 |
| India | 1 | 3 |

I am new to Pandas and Exploratory data science. Please help here

Answer (score 4):

You can try `pivot_table`

```py
df['Is Rich?'] = df['Is Rich?'].replace({'Yes': 'Rich', 'No': 'Poor'})
out = df.pivot_table(index='Country', columns='Is Rich?', values='Person', aggfunc='count')
```

```
print(out)

Is Rich?  Poor  Rich
Country
India        3     1
US           1     3
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
converted = df.assign(Rich=df['Is Rich?'].eq('Yes')).eval('Poor = ~Rich').groupby('Country').agg({'Rich': 'sum', 'Poor': 'sum'})

print(converted)
```

```
         Rich  Poor
Country            
India       1     3
US          3     1
```

However, if you want to plot it as a barplot, the following format might work best with a plotting library like [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org):

```
plot_df = converted.reset_index().melt(id_vars='Country', value_name='No. of people', var_name='Status')
print(plot_df)
```

```
  Country Status  No. of people
0   India   Rich              1
1      US   Rich              3
2   India   Poor              3
3      US   Poor              1
```

Then, with `seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.barplot(x='Country', hue='Status', y='No. of people', data=plot_df)
```

Resulting plot:

[image]